# Django error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mydjangoprojstudentsstudents'

Tags: django, git-bash, django-errors

This is the error in my git bash console.

[image]

I'm just beginning Django hence don't know where to search for the error.

**My settings.py file**

[image]

**My urls.py file**

[image]

**My apps**

[image]

Please let me know if I need to provide any more info.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are missing commas after your app names/strings in the INSTALLED_APPS list

Comment: Please, don't post your code with pictures. You should paste it in with code formatting.